# Rails 3: Ordering Objects that Belong_To

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

On my site, every Post has many Comments. The user can sort comments in several ways, and although I can get this to work using sort!, I'm certain there's a way to do this using a MySQL query. Unfortunately, the comments return unsorted when I try methods like:

```
@post.comments.order('created_at DESC')
```

I've also tried:

```
Comment.where("post_id = ?", @post.id).order('created_at DESC')
```

Though I get the same unsorted results. How else might I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and see if it works!.. Im sure there might be more efficient ways to do it but this will do the trick regardless

```
@post= @post.comments.sort_by(&:created_at)
@post = @post.reverse
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Yep, that definitely works. I've got something similar now, using sort!. I'd prefer that MySQL do the sorting, though, as it's considerably faster than Ruby. There must be a way to get it to work. I'll let you know if I figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mysql `date` or `time` function might help. I didnt try the following snippet but it will be somewhat like this with `date`:

```
Comment.where("post_id = ?", @post.id, :order => 'date(created_at) DESC')
```

**EDIT:**

Tried with `sqlite` and the following worked for me

```
Comment.where("post_id = ?", @post.id, :order => 'time(created_at) DESC')
```

The same approach should work for mysql also. I would suggest to create a `scope` like

```
class Comment < AR::Base
     scope :latest_first, :order => 'time(created_at) DESC'
end
```

and use it like

```
Comment.where("post_id = ?", @post.id).latest_first #OR
Comment.latest_first.where("post_id = ?", @post.id)
```

Whichever sounds better to you :)

Comment: I don't understand why, but none of the MySQL approaches work. These should work, though, right? Meaning that there must be some other problem. For the time being I'm able to get the results I want by using sort!, but I'm just baffled by why I can't do the ordering via the database.

Comment: Can you add couple of sample rows and the command you are running. Also try to add the snippet from log. It might be helpful.